# How to make DevExpress DataGridView HeaderFontAttributes bold in C# in Xamarin.Forms App?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, devexpress

I have a datagridview like this below.

**Xaml:**

```
 <dxg:DataGridView x:Name="dataTable" ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicRaporList}"   >
        </dxg:DataGridView>
```

**C# code :**

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str, (typeof(DataTable)));
            
dataTable.ItemsSource = dt;
```

I want to create this from c# side because I can not control these column's HeaderFontAttributes. I thought if I create datagridview from c# side I could control HeaderFontAttributes. Basicly, I want a bold text in header. This data table is dynamic I can not add column in xaml side. This makes processes hard.

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/403565/data-grid/net-maui-data-grid-appearance#example)

```
    <!--Customize the appearance of column headers.-->
    <dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderAppearance>
        <dxg:ColumnHeaderAppearance BackgroundColor="#333333" BorderColor="#515151" 
                               FontSize="16" FontColor="#929292" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                               HorizontalLineThickness="2"/>
    </dxg:DataGridView.ColumnHeaderAppearance>
```

Comment: When I add this code block it says this : "The member "ColumnHeaderAppearance" is no recognized or is not accessible."

Comment: sorry, that example is for MAUI.  In Xamarin the property is [ColumnHeaderStyle](https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/400845/xamarin-forms/data-grid/examples/grid-custom-appearance)

Comment: xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/xamarin/2014/forms/datagrid" I declare dxg like this but in example its like this : xmlns:dxg="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid;assembly=DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid" 
They use maui in example.

Comment: Thank you Jason, this xamarin forms code works well.